# How can I process one line of the dynamic table?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a dynamic table and when I read the barcode, I pull the code and the product name from the database and display it over the texts. When the barcode is not registered, I need to delete the data of the relevant line. How can I do? I think I made a mistake in my index counter. Can you help?

//Barcodes are defined in my sql table. When a user enters a registered barcode in the dynamic table row in the user panel, my texts are filled with the information in my sql table automatically. Then, when I replace the same barcode location with an undefined barcode, the data from the previous barcode on my texts stops. In the code I share, I do the operation on the first line, I cannot just process the line I am on.

```
    DataTable dttb = (DataTable)ViewState["datatable"];
    int index = 0;
    try
    {

        if (dttb.Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < dttb.Rows.Count; i++)
            {
                TextBox t1 = (TextBox)GridView1.Rows[i].Cells[1].FindControl("stokodtxt");
                TextBox t2 = (TextBox)GridView1.Rows[i].Cells[2].FindControl("barkodtxt");
                TextBox t3 = (TextBox)GridView1.Rows[i].Cells[3].FindControl("uruntxt");

                SqlDataAdapter brkd = new SqlDataAdapter("select * from aa_barkodisim where bar_kodu='" + t2.Text + "'", bagla);
                DataTable tablo = new DataTable();
                brkd.Fill(tablo);
                t1.Text = tablo.Rows[0][0].ToString();
                t3.Text = tablo.Rows[0][2].ToString();                      
            }
            bagla.Close();
            index++;
        }
        else
        {
            Labelmesaj.Text = "Hata Olustu!";
        }
    }

    catch (Exception)
    {

        Labelmesaj.Text = "<strong style = 'color:red;'>GİRİLEN BARKOD TANIMLI DEĞİL !</strong";


        TextBox t1 = (TextBox)GridView1.Rows[0].Cells[1].FindControl("stokodtxt");
        TextBox t3 = (TextBox)GridView1.Rows[0].Cells[3].FindControl("uruntxt"); 
        TextBox t4 = (TextBox)GridView1.Rows[0].Cells[4].FindControl("skttxt");
        TextBox t5 = (TextBox)GridView1.Rows[0].Cells[5].FindControl("irsaliyetxt");
        TextBox t6 = (TextBox)GridView1.Rows[0].Cells[6].FindControl("gelenadettxt");
        TextBox t7 = (TextBox)GridView1.Rows[0].Cells[7].FindControl("eksikadettxt");
        TextBox t8 = (TextBox)GridView1.Rows[0].Cells[8].FindControl("aciklamatxt");

        t1.Text = "";
        t3.Text = "";
        t4.Text = "";
        t5.Text = "";
        t6.Text = "";
        t7.Text = "";
        t8.Text = "";
    }
```